# No mistake but I still get underfull \hbox error

Tags: warnings

I get famous `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)` error. This error doesn't effect the output, as in image [image: pdf that I get]

How can I overcome this issue ?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\title{Notes}
\maketitle{}

\[ \vec{\nabla} = \vec{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\vec{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+ \vec{k}\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \]
\[ \vec{\nabla}f \to Gradient \quad \quad \vec{\nabla} . \vec{V}\to Diverjans \quad \quad \vec{\nabla}\times \vec{V}\to Curl \]
\[ Material \quad Derivative \longrightarrow \frac{D}{Dt}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\vec{V} . \vec{\nabla} \]

\noindent
Acceleration = Local Acceleration + Advective(Convective) Acceleration \\
Example: flow passing nozzle; local accel.=0 but advective accel.$\neq$ 0\newline
\[ \vec{a_{x}}= \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + v\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + w\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not an error, just warning.

Comment: But normally I shouldn't get this kind of messages, should I ?

Comment: Delete `\newline`.

Comment: Off topic: I'd use `\cdot` in divergent definition.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I will change it as you said.

Comment: Also, I'd write: `\begin{align*}
\vec{\nabla}f &\to \text{Gradient} &  \vec{\nabla} \cdot  \vec{V}&\to \text{Diverjans} & \vec{\nabla}\times \vec{V}&\to \text{Curl}
\end{align*}
\[ \text{Material  Derivative} \to \frac{D}{Dt}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\vec{V} \cdot  \vec{\nabla} \]`

Comment: the `\newline` is the mistake tex does tell you the line that is at fault, also you should not have consecutive `\[\]` display math, instead use a mult-line display such as `gather*` Also the `\noindent` should never be needed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `\newline` before the displayed equation.

A MWE for the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World\newline % no line follows, causing underfull \hbox
\[ E = mc^2 \]
\end{document}
```